# GridLine on top of a Bar Chart in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, bar-chart, gridlines

Is it possible to get a GridLine over a BartChart ?
Gridlines draw it under and Mesh does not seem to work with BarChart.

```
BarChart[{Range[10], Range[10]}, 
         ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
         GridLines -> {None, {4}}, 
         GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thick]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be done via a method option:

```
BarChart[{Range[10], Range[10]}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 GridLines -> {None, {4}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thick],
  Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image]

(this *should* work for any graphic.)

Comment: At Brett, 
wonderful, thank You ! For some reason @Brett, makes Brett and @ disappear.

Comment: Is this documented?  I don't think I've come across that before.

Comment: It appears that there is also a Graphics option  `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> True}` See [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Aug/msg00164.html) for Mathgroup discussion by David Park. Never heard of either myself.

Comment: @500, the @ and Brett disappears because it is unambiguous as to who your referring to.

Comment: I must second the question of whether it is documented or not.

Comment: `Method` isn't documented as an option for either `Graphics` or `BarChart` in the version 8 documentation - time to add to my [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087149/how-can-one-find-undocumented-options-or-option-values-in-mathematica][question].

Comment: @Verbeia: `Method` is indeed a documented option of `Graphics` (and thus of `BarChart`.)  Specifically it's listed in the options table under Notes, although neither `BarChart` nor `Graphics` contains examples of its use.

Comment: Ah - I see, but it's not in the list of options given in the documentation under the "Options" heading. I'll revise the question accordingly.

Comment: @500 see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99261) for a possible explanation of the disappearing @-username.  Personally, I preferred things as they were.

Answer (score 4):

Your other option would be to draw the gridline explicitly with [Epilog](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html). This would be the solution if you wanted some gridlines (e.g. vertical ones) behind and some in front.
I have added some other options in case you don't actually want the gridline to bleed over the axes.

```
BarChart[{Range[10], Range[10]}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 Epilog -> {Orange, Thick, Line[{{0, 4}, {3, 4}}]}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: @Vebeia,Thank you for your attention.